# Get if someone is using a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Like the title says, i need to know if someone is using a combobox.
i.e. when the box is dropped down.

Is there any method to get this? Maybe an actionlistener?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#firePopupMenuWillBecomeVisible()

Comment: Use [JComboBox#addPopupMenuListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addPopupMenuListener(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`JComboBox#addPopupMenuListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addPopupMenuListener%28javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener%29):

```
comboBox.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener()
{
    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
    {
        // ...  
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
    {
        // ...  
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e)
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```